# How can I change the marker color in leaflet without making a new icon

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I want to change the color from default marker

```
var marker = L.marker( [latitude, longitude], 
                       {markercolor:'red'}).addTo(map).bindPopup(data.Name);
```